# s.getPreviousValue plugin not working

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

On Page A, I have a `s.tl()` call on click of "Link A" where I am filling `evar1` and triggering off an event1. This link A leads to Page B

Code on link click in page A

```
$(document).on('click','.nav.navbar-nav.subnav-breadcrumb a',function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('create group')!=-1){
        s.events = "event1";
        s.linkTrackEvents = "event1";
        s.eVar1 = "Step 1";
        s.linkTrackVars = "eVar1,events";
        s.tl(true,'o','Step 1');    
    }
});
```

On pageload of Page B, in the do Plugins sections, I try to get the value of `eVar` set in the prev `s.tl()` call by the following code

```
function s_doPlugins(s) {
    console.log(s.getPreviousValue(s.eVar1,'cookie_name','event1') 
}
```

However, I get the value as 'undefined'. Does `getPreviousValue()` plugin not work on previous `s.tl()` calls? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned in the documentation](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/getPreviousValue.html), since you are using the 3rd argument of `s.getPreviousValue()`, it will only store and trigger if the specified event is set (in both your case and doc example, that is `event1`).

Since you are setting `event` in the link click, `s.getPreviousValue()` triggers because `s_doPlugins` gets called on all `s.t()` and `s.tl()` calls, so at that point you should see the value in your `cookie_name` cookie (look in `s_pers` cookie if you are using combined cookie plugin).

However, on the next page (Page B) `event1` isn't set, so when `s_doPlugins` gets called for the on-page `s.t()` call, `s.getPreviousValue()` will not update/return previous value.

In other words, when you specify an event in the 3rd argument, the plugin **only** triggers when the specified event is present in `s.events`. Basically first thing it does is check if 3rd arg exists then go through `s.events` and see if it's in there. If it's not, that's it, function ends with no return value (and that's why you get `undefined` returned).

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish but in my experience there aren't many use cases for specifying an event in the 3rd argument.