# Adobe DTM s.getPreviousValue() not working when used correctly?

Tags: adobe-analytics

This question is **different** from [s.getPreviousValue plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094075/s-getpreviousvalue-plugin-not-working)

Here's the difference: unlike the other question, which had some incorrect parameters, I am using the sample code straight from the documentation:

```
s.prop1 = s.getPreviousValue(s.pageName,'gpv_pn','');
```

The code is placed inside `s_doPlugins` like it's supposed to, in the *Library Management -> Code Configuration -> Custom* section of the Adobe Analytics tool configuration. Code is hosted in DTM.

Unfortunately the cookie `gpv_pn` is consistently set to the string "no value".

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this set after s.pageName is? Generally, this is a given, because doPlugins runs as the last thing before a beacon fires, but if you're setting pageName in doPlugins as well, you'd need to make sure getPreviousValue runs after it. 
If you add something like this:
_satellite.notify("getPreviousValue is running, my pageName is "+s.pageName)
Does your console show you the pageName for the current page?

Comment: You nailed it! s.pageName is blank in doPlugins. Now I wonder why ?!